# warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'BOOST_STRINGIZE'

Tags: c++, boost

Im getting some errors any time i try to compile my program and run the boost tests i have wrote. They look like this:

```
 1>c:\local\boost_1_65_1\boost\test\unit_test_suite.hpp(383): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'BOOST_STRINGIZE'
1>c:\local\boost_1_65_1\boost\test\unit_test_suite.hpp(383): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'BOOST_DO_STRINGIZE'
1>c:\local\boost_1_65_1\boost\test\unit_test_suite.hpp(383): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ','
1>c:\local\boost_1_65_1\boost\test\unit_test_suite.hpp(383): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

This is the only test i've tried running, Also i did include #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE in a different .cpp file.

```
#include"vector_set.hpp"
#include<boost\test\auto_unit_test.hpp>

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(empty_test)
    {
        vector_set<int> vs;

        BOOST_CHECK(vs.empty());

        vector_set<int> vs1 = { 1,3,4,6,7,5,3 };

        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(vs1.empty(), false);
    }
```

Anyone have any idea how to solve this? Boost has caused me problems every step of the way and i just want it to start working properly. Thank you.

Comment: erm. We're not psychics. Post the relevant code that triggers it (I say you forgot to pass a parameter to a macro, like `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` or something like that)

Comment: my bad, added my test case to show.

Comment: What version of boost? The code is fine. Have you checked the preprocessor output. Mmm. You can't. I'd try checking what `empty_test` actually is (is it overridden by a macro define?)

Comment: im using 1.65.1, i changed of empty_test to name to something completely random and still am getting the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Try including `boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp` _before_ all other headers (beware of stdafx.h if you use precompiled headers). If that doesn't give clues, I'd start eliminating code until you find a culprit. If it's just the header, my only idea now would be that you're finding conflicting versions of boost headers in the include path(s)